# Winium - how to access tool bar item if that bar doesn't have child

Tags: java, automation

I am using Winium + Java for automation testing of Windows application, and trying to access tool bar menu.
When I tried to detect elements using UI Automation Verify, I couldn't see child elements under tool bar element like below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDEiG.png)

But my tool bar definitely has sub menu items like screenshot and I need to access them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk4eu.png)

I tried below java code, but it didn't work

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id('59398'));
el.click();
WebElement child = el.findElement(By.name('Start'));
child.click();
```

when I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.name"Start').click();
```

it clicked my windows start menu, not my application's menu.

Is there any way to access items under this tool bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use another UI Inspector 
eg. UI SPY or Inspector.exe

Probably your ID is not a AutomationID (process id?)

You should find a main window (parent of your app) (Example for calc) and get a parameter like AutomationId, ClassName or Name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see this is MFC application, and this is an app side MFC library problem. If you hover mouse over toolbar button using Inspect.exe, the info is available but you can't reach this button from the hierarchy (the buttons have no parent somehow). Possible workaround involves combined Win32 API and UI Automation approach:

1. get button rectangle using Win32 API (but there is no text).
2. use `ElementFromPoint` method of UI Automation API and get actual texts to choose the right button.

P.S. My suggestion is applicable for Java + Winium in theory. But I can't estimate the complexity because I'm not a Java expert. So below is Python solution.

We have plans to implemented this mixed way in pywinauto. See [issue #413](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/413). It contains Python code sample how to do that. We've had no chance to integrate it yet.

```
from ctypes.wintypes import tagPOINT
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application().start(r'.\apps\MFC_samples\RebarTest.exe')

menu_bar = app.RebarTest.MenuBar.wrapper_object()
point = menu_bar.button(0).rectangle().mid_point()
point = menu_bar.client_to_screen(point)

elem = pywinauto.uia_defines.IUIA().iuia.ElementFromPoint(tagPOINT(point[0], point[1]))
element = pywinauto.uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo(elem)
print(element.name)
```